# Is there a way to use the `with`-statement in a closure in python?

Tags: python, closures, with-statement

I want to use a [Context Manager Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) inside of a closure such that it's lifetime spans the lifetime of the enclosed function.

A (not working) version communicating my intent could be:

```py
class CtxMgr:
    def __enter__(self):
        print('enter')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('exit')
        return False

def closure():
    with CtxMgr() as mgr:
        def enclosed():
            print('called')
        return enclosed


cl = closure()
print('generated')
cl()
```

But this obviously does not work since the context of the `with`-statement ends when `enclosed` is returned. This can be seen in the output:

```
enter
exit
generated
called
```

If the `CtxMgr` were kept alive while the enclosed function exists it should look like this:

```
enter
generated
called
exit
```

Is it possible to have the `CtxMgr` stay alive while the closure exists?

Comment: This can be done with `weakref`s . Not sure if you still want this answer, but if yes, then, you have to be  aware of 2 things: (1) there might be an arbitrary number of objects created inside the `with` block. Do you want `__exit__` to only run all of them are deleted? And (2): by "lifetime' you mean when the returned function is de-referenced, right? not "called"? (in your example code, a `del cl` would have to be called after `cl()` . Otherwise, for how many calls should the `with` block be good? just 1? a parametrizable number?

Comment: It you want it to be valid for a single call, a simple decorator will do it, instead of the `with` statement. - I will add that answer right away.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve the essence of what you are trying to accomplish by using a decorator:

```py
from functools import wraps

class CtxMgr:
    def __enter__(self):
        print('enter')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('exit')
        return False

def use_CtxMgr(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def enclosed(*args,**kwargs):
        with CtxMgr():
            return f(*args,**kwargs)
    return enclosed

@use_CtxMgr
def my_function():
    print('Called')


my_function()
```

Prints:

```None
enter
Called
exit
```

Comment: You are right, but it is not possible to pass arguments to the ContextManager from the function, would it?

Comment: @AndreasFranek I am not sure what you are asking. But it is possible to create a function decorator that takes arguments and those arguments could be passed to the context manager.

Comment: I meant `use_CtxMgr` cannot be passed arguments from `my_function`. It would be possible to, e.g., take the first argument passed to the enclosed function to create the `CtxMgr`, but that seems a little convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

If by "lifetime" you mean to last a single call of the returned function, after which the  "exit" should be executed, that can be done with a specially crafted decorator:

```
class CtxMgr:
    def __enter__(self):
        print('enter')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('exit')
        return False

def ctx_mgr_decorator(ctxmgr):
    def deco(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with ctxmgr:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return deco

def closure():
    @ctx_mgr_decorator(CtxMgr())
    def enclosed():
        print('called')
    return enclosed


cl = closure()
print('generated')
cl()
```

Output:

```
generated
enter
called
exit
```

I think the idea @booboo's answer was more or less this, but unfortunatelly his answer did not preserve the main characteristic from your code which is exactly having an enclosed function, which can access nonlocal variables in `closure`. This one does that.

But note that this is not the "lifetime" of the enclosed function: the context manager will be entered and exited *each* *time* the returned function is called. For "lifetime" the idea should be that `__exit__` would be executed exactly once, when the returned function is disposed off, regardless of how many times it is called. If you need that, a more complex solution is required, and I can only devise one making use of weakrefs, so that we can trigger code when the returned object is deleted (it would be more complicated code, but feasible)

Comment: I have not worked with weakrefs yet. Could you kindly provide such an example?